# Save one particular object with core data in Swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3

I've fetched data from a web service. From this data, I've created managed objects by following commands:

```
let videoTitle = snippet["title"] as! String
let videoDescription = snippet["description"] as! String
let videoThumbnail = ((snippet["thumbnails"] as! NSDictionary)["default"] as! NSDictionary)["url"] as! String
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
    return
}
let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "YTVideo",
                                        in: managedContext)!
let video = YTVideo(entity: entity, insertInto: managedContext)
video.videoID = videoID
video.videoTitle = videoTitle
video.videoDescription = videoDescription
video.videoThumbnail = videoThumbnail
video.isFavorite = false
ytVideos.append(video)
```

In the code, `ytVideos` is an array.
Now user will have the option to save an object. If he chooses to save the object, I want to put it into the persistent store using command:

```
managedContext.save()
```

However, this will save all the objects I've created.
How can I save a particular object?
Of course, I can always create another model, let the user play with objects of this model and then use the model `YTVideo` for core data, but I'd like to use only one model for my application for simplicity. How can I do it?
Many thanks.

Comment: Create only those core data object that you want to save other object should be class object only .

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to save just one object is to make a child managed object context and then create your specific object in that context. Now it will not really be saved to the persistent store until you call save on the parent context. If you really want to have it persist independent of all of the other objects, then create a peer context. Saving from the peer will push to the store. That said, you will then need to read those values into the context to use them.

Comment: How to create peer managed contexts? I've tried using 'newBackgroundContext()' but it doesn't seem to work. If I use 'viewContext', it always refers to the same managed context.

Comment: A peer context is one that uses the same persistent store and is on the queue of your preference. As contexts can have many parameters unique to your application, I cannot write your code to instantiate a new context.